# Profile EntityFramework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the following sample code:

```
  Context context = new Context();
  Repository repository = new Repository(context);

  Post post = repository.First<Post>(x => x.Id == 1);

  Model model = new Model {
    Created = cube.Created,
    Id = cube.Id,
    Name = cube.Name,
    Pack = cube.Pack.Id,
    Mimes = context.Files.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.Mime).ToList()
  };
```

I need to find which SQL queries are being sent to the database.

How can I profile the EF queries using SQL Express and VS 2012?

Is there any tool for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1. Examine the query by printing it at runtime using `((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901917/1070291 (I think this only works for queries so may not be the best in the above scenario)
2. Use SQL Profiler which is built into management studio
3. Use [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) (a very good third party tool with a trial version, this is what I use to analyse queries)

Answer (score 19):

The [EF Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) specified in the other answer is a beast - wildly powerful, but that doesn't come for free ($$, disk space and time). It's also made by [Oren Eini](http://ayende.com/blog) of NHibernate and [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) fame.

The tools I like to use in a pinch are way, way more light-weight, and of course can't begin to compare to EF Prof in terms of features - but the cost ($$, time and disk) is, or approaches, zero.

I tested these lightweight profilers with EF on LocalDb, but their main use cases are the more traditional Sql Server flavors (including Express).

### ExpressProfiler

By far the easiest to use one (and also the most bare-bones-show-me-the-SQL-statements-kthxbye) is [ExpressProfiler on CodePlex](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/).

[image]

And the whole program is a single 126 KB EXE ! Now that's lightweight!

### AnjLab Sql Profiler

The other one is the one from [DataWizard](http://www.datawizard.com/), which used to be free (apparently prices now start at $5).

Somebody managed to save a [snapshot on GitHub](https://github.com/ren85/free-sql-server-profiler) (including xcopy-installable binaries) when it was open-source.

The executable presents itself as "AnjLab Sql Profiler" and allows some filtering of the displayed events - but this strength is also its weakness, as there are sooo many event types that can be enabled/disabled. If everything is selected, the output is overwhelmingly verbose.

A saner output can be obtain by only selecting specific events.

[image]

Here are the events I have selected in order to get the above output:

[image]

Comment: I didnt know you could use kthxbye in a technical discussion but here you go.

EDIT:
AND I LOVE IT! Im gonna use it everywhere starting now. kthxbye!