# EF or Ado.net profiling

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Is there any way to profile EF or Ado.net queires which are executing inside a assembly without making any modification on the assembly. Need somthing like this [VSInstr](http://automationbyexample.blogspot.qa/2013/04/visual-studio-2010-code-coverage-of-iis.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Profile EntityFramework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812256/profile-entityframework)

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio's Ultimate / Enterprise editions support [IntiliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572114(v=vs.120).aspx) in which you can find outgoing `ADO.Net` queries.

If products are not available to you can examine the Database's logs.
Assuming you are using MSSQLServer you can use [SQL Server Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669421/how-to-monitor-just-t-sql-commands-in-sql-profiler).

Comment: Thanks for your time. This requires VS IDE to be installed on the my development build server, which I am not allowed to. Is there any way I can trace the log through my compiled version of .dll files and .pdb files to achieve the result. Like dot net performance tools does the code tracing through assemblies. Please correct if I am wrong.