# DbContext slow on debug build

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, dbcontext

<sup>Note: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925972/why-is-dbcontext-savechanges-10x-slower-in-debug-mode), but I don't have Intellitrace as I'm on Pro, not Ultimate</sup>

When I run my application on a debug build, it takes a long time to open the `DBContext` for the first time. Then it has the expected slightly larger amount of lag afterwards. In the Release build, it's about 20x faster. My app is a WPF app, relying on the EF6-SQLite converter  from [Brice Lambson's blog](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/systemdatasqlite-on-entity-framework-6.html) and a local database (SSD, so no real storage bottleneck). I'm running VS2013 Pro from Dreamspark. It's compiled to MSIL (All CPU). Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in version 6,0,2, currently available as beta version from Nuget

Comment: 6.0.2 isn't making it better.

Comment: try NGen! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/31/ef6-performance-issues.aspx

Comment: It improves it a but not much. Well, it varies. Sometimes it runs flawlessly, sometimes it's nearly as slow as before.