# Performance for using 2 where clauses in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

In LINQ-to-Entities you can query entities by doing:

```
var students = SchoolContext.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "Foo" && s.Id == 1);
```

I know that behind the scenes it will be translated to SQL to something similar to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Name = 'Foo' AND Id = 1
```

However is there a difference (with respect to performance) if I write:

```
var students = 
    SchoolContext.Students
        .Where(s => s.Name == "Foo")
        .Where(s => s.Id == 1);
```

Will it be translated to the same SQL query? From my understanding `.Where()` will return `IEnumerable<T>` so the second `.Where()` will filter the entities in-memory instead of translating the `IQueryable<T>` to SQL, is that correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first `.Where()` clause will still return an `IQueryable<T>`.  As long as you are operating on an `IQueryable<T>` it will continue building up the SQL query and execute it when the collection needs to be brought into memory (eg: as @anaximander stated when used in a `foreach` loop or `ToList()` operation.

Therefore:

```
SchoolContext.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "Foo").Where(s => s.Id == 1);
```

Still translates into:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Name = 'Foo' AND Id = 1
```

Whilst the below 2 statements will translate into the same query:

```
SchoolContext.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "Foo").Where(s => s.Id == 1);
SchoolContext.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "Foo" && s.Id == 1);
```

Comment: A good way to debug this without even using a profiler is to breakpoint your code and hover over the variable within Visual Studio, the way you'd normally do to see the value of something. It will show you the generated SQL when you expand it.

Comment: @SLC: Note that what you say works only when using the modern Entity Framework's `DbContext` API, and the associated `DbQuery`. If he is using `ObjectContext` and the associated `ObjectQuery`, then a call to `ToTraceString` is required instead. (Reason: `DbQuery`'s implementation of `ToString` calls `ObjectQuery.ToTraceString`).

Comment: @SLC Is that a new feature for Entity Framework?  When I used EF (circa EF 3.5), that definitely did not work - the only way to see the generated SQL was with an SQL profiler attached to the database *(or add some [convoluted code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/238419))*

Comment: Could be a new feature, or could be what @Jean mentioned above I guess. I'm using .NET 4.5 so I can't really tell you.

Comment: @Danny: [`ObjectQuery.ToTraceString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) has existed since .NET 3.5 SP1. But it looks like that is what you are calling "convoluted code". (Well, I guess that is why they put that on the `ToString` call afterwards.)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it contains the most details

Answer (score 7):

First Where returns `IQueryable<T>` so there will be no performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will be the same query.

You can **compose** a more and more complex query by [**fluently**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) chaining the [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx)s returned by each Linq operation. The statement is not generated and sent to the server until you evaluate the results.

You can check that the actual query generated by debugging and hovering over the query [or doing a `ToTraceString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901814/debugging-entity-framework-sql-statements) or using a tool like SQLProfiler to monitor the database server.

Answer (score 1):

The two should produce the same SQL; `IQueryable` is smart in that it doesn't actually evaluate until it needs to. The second `.Where()` should add to the first, and then whenever you use `.ToList()`, `.Count()`, `foreach` or anything that needs to know what's *in* the `IQueryable`, it'll generate the SQL, query the database and give you the result.

Answer (score 1):

Get [Linqpad](http://linqpad.com), and try the different queries there. You can Add a connection to your entities directly, run the queries, and see which SQL is generated in each case. Excellent way to experiment with Linq.