# Check what entities to include

Tags: entity-framework, database-performance

Is there any way to analyze what entities have been loaded during one query request?
Currently I'm using lazy loading and it has huge performance impact. So I would want to analyze query somehow and .Include all related objects.

Comment: Could you show your codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging Entity Framework SQL statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901814/debugging-entity-framework-sql-statements)

Comment: I just want to get Entities that was loaded during my query. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `ObjectMaterialized` event of your context.

```
ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

PS. If you work with `DbContext`, you need to retrieve `ObjectContext` from it first:

```
var context = new YourDbContext();
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
```

Comment: Looks like what I want! Let me check it and I'll get back and mark it as accepted answer! Thank you!

Comment: it will be raised for each single object retrieved as a result of query execution...

Comment: I'm not aware of functionality you are developing, but take a note of this remark from documentation to avoid possible bugs `" If an object with the same key value exists in the object context, the Entity Framework will not recreate the object and this event will not be raised. "`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Is there any way to get object hierarchy? I mean it raised with Entity only and I don't know which entity it was called from. For example I get raised event on Order entity and then on Customer. That would need to .Include("Order"."Customer") and so on..

Comment: I think it is kind of tree - it first materializes parent entity and goes down. you can implement custom logic based on sequence of events raised and check what navigation properties are loaded.